# Wordpress file upload gives HTTP error

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, http-status-code-404, filesize

When uploading a 50MB file in WordPress through any of the methods it provides, I experienced an error message saying

```
HTTP error.
```

with no further hint what has happened. I tried uploading other types of similar size and different file types of smaller size. Only files above a certain size failed no matter what type and all types of smaller size succeeded.

I raised maximum file and post size in php.ini (`upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`) and the network settings of WP up to four times the size of the file but to no avail.

I found out that the error was 404 even though the file which 404ed was *physically* there. Upon further inspection of the answer I found out that IIS answered with a more detailed error code of "404.13" which further hints to the request filtering module and the solution (below)

Comment: Did you tried uploading it through FTP? If you have access to it ofc.

Comment: I have access to the file system but that would have been a work-around and neither an explanation for nor a fix of that error.

Answer (score 1):

This problem **is related to the file's size** but has nothing to do with WordPress or PHP or the filesystem but with settings in IIS.

In IIS there is a feature called **"Request Filtering"** where you can set filtering rules for requests based on various things like HTTP verbs, file extensions, and so on. Unfortunately the UI of IIS often is not very clear and hides important links in the side bar on the right side which puts things out of attention on wide monitors.

## Solution

- Open **"Request Filtering"**
- Click on **"Edit Feature Settings..."** in the sidebar
- change the value of **"Maximum allowed content length (Bytes)"**